# in android, how to justify whether there is such a file based on the file path, like "/sdcard/a.jpg"?

Tags: android

when given a file address, like "/sdcard/a.txt", or "/sdcard/a.jpg", how to justify whether there is such a file? 
I have tried:
`File file = new File("/sdcard/a.txt)"
if(file == null)`
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`File.exists()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#exists()):

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/a.txt")

if (file.exists()) {
    // file exists
} else {
    // file does not exist
}
```